# Save sql file after doing insert wpdb

Tags: wpdb

My code below takes an xml file and inserts it into a database table. However, I would also like to save the full insert query as a backup. Is it possible to write out the query built by wpdb so that I can save it to a  file?

```
function lc_course_database_convert_to_sql( $file ) {
    global $wpdb;
    //$wpdb->show_errors();
    $xml = simplexml_load_file( $file['url'] );
    $tablename   = $wpdb->prefix . 'courses';
    $mydata = new SimpleXmlIterator( $file['url'], 0, true );
    for ( $mydata->rewind();$mydata->valid();$mydata->next() ) {
        //create an array with the column names and corresponding values
        $insertarray = array();
        foreach ( $mydata->current() as $k=>$v ) {
            $insertarray[$k]= (string)$v;
        }
        $wpdb->insert(
            $tablename,
            $insertarray,
            array(
                '%d',
                '%s',
                '%d',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%d',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%d',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial! `$wpdb->last_query` will hold it. :)

For more extensive log you might want to define `SAVEQUERIES` constant to `true` in configuration. Full log then will be available in `$wpdb->queries`. It's off by default for performance reasons.